# Using a custom VB.NET Theme in a C# Application

Tags: c#, vb.net, themes

I've found a nice VB.NET Theme online, however, my application was C#, so I did the most logical thing, which is creating a new VB.NET Class Library, using the theme class, and then using the DLL through my toolbox's items.

This is the theme's code: http://pastebin.com/bxM7wtyN.
Note that the classes were not set to public, but I did so, as I thought that's why the error popped up. This is the error I'm getting.

[image]

Why's that, exactly? I think everything looks fine, and the theme's code works for everyone as they're using VB.NET, but not for me.

Answer (score 1):

Uh, You have 2 ways. Find a c# version or try to convert into c# from vb.net.

Comment: Please provide more details or an example to clarify your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the code to a blank file in your project, and then build the project but don't run it. Now in Visual Studio, open the Toolbox and the new controls should be at the top.